# ionic 2 create dynamic data

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I want to channel_name_1 automatically increase and go channel_name_2 , channel_name_3 ; if statement where it go

Look to //THİS LİNE

"{\"channel_list\": {\"channel_name_1\": \"deneme\", \"channel_name_0\": \"Ev s\u0131cakl\u0131k takibi\", \"channel_id_0\": 136, \"channel_id_1\": 137}}"

I wanto to take channel_name_1 , channel_name_0 values.

Thanx to now

```
var veri;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );  
    //headers.append('Authorization' , 'Basic '+ btoa(tok));
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams = {
    token: "381f13d7056-ce5fe474919",
    user_id: "71",
    }

    var veris="channel_name_";
    this.http.post("https://iothook.com/api/v1.0/channels/", postParams, options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        veri = data['_body'];
        console.log(veri);       
        veri= veri.slice(1, -1);
        veri = veri.replace(/\\/g, "");
        veri = JSON.parse(veri);
        for(var i = 0 ; i<2;i++)
          {
              veris+=i;
              this.veriler.push({channelname: veri.channel.channel_name_1}); //THİS LİNE
              console.log(veri.channel_name_1);
          }
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how in a loop to to change the value of a string?

Comment: No , I geting Json and parsing. And ı use parsed veriable. look to this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what youre asking, but I think you want to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    veris += i;
    this.veriler.push({ channelname: veri.channel['channel_name_' + (i + 1) }); //THİS LİNE
    console.log(veri.channel['channel_name_' + (i + 1));
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? In what way does it not work?

Comment: it say me , you cant use [ after this veri.channel.        and I edited my post can you see again

Comment: Oh sorry! Remove the `.` before the `[`

Comment: With your last edit you changed the question at issue, from asking how to iterate through an objects properties, to asking how exactly to get the properties you need. This is not ok. If you feel the question before the last edit was answered you accept the answer and open up a new question. As the info in the edit view says:  How to edit  "clarify meaning without changing it"

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to upvote if you found this answer useful!